# Why is the slippage constraint for one moving cylinder and one fixed cylinder $r(\phi - \theta)=R \theta$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, constrained-dynamics

Why is the slippage constraint for one moving cylinder and one fixed cylinder $r(\phi - \theta)=R \theta$? Every time I write it down on paper I get the result $r\phi = R \theta$. I am not sure if I am supposed to include a rotating frame. Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Your diagram is not wrong - but maybe the definition of $\phi$ and $\theta$ are different. For one thing - usually people measure both angles in the same direction - and you seem to have one measured clockwise and the other counterclockwise. Can you show where your original expression comes from?

Comment: yes , if you can give us a link to one of those solutions we could check which of your assumptions differ from the solution shown in the literature

Comment: There isn't a need to discuss rotating frames, try defining both angles from the north vertical, rather than the opposite verticals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few clarifications first: I will assume that the bigger cylinder (radius $R$) is not moving, and I will be doing the problem in this frames. I will assume that both $\theta$ and $\phi$ are positive in the clockwise direction. This is against convention but it'll make a few negative signs disappear, and you many find it easier to think this way given how the cylinders are moving in this problem.

I used to have the same confusion about this particular no-slip condition. I understand that you got the result $r\phi=R\theta$ by imagining that the two cylinders are connected gears, and then writing down the arc length that each cylinder moves through as they rotate (or by an equivalent thought process). The problem is that this only works when the cylinders are fixed at their centers and undergo no translation. To see why $r(\phi-\theta)=R\theta$, I suggest that we think about velocities.

The actual constraint here is that there must be no slippage between the two cylinders (i.e. the relative velocity between the surfaces of the two cylinders at the point of contact is 0). We can first ask the question, if the smaller cylinder was only undergoing translation and no rotation, how fast is its surface slipping past the surface of the larger cylinder? The answer is $(R+r)\dot{\theta}$, since that is the translational velocity of the smaller cylinder, and this velocity is perpendicular to the surface of the larger cylinder.

Now to impose the no slippage constraint, the surface of the smaller cylinder has to rotate at exactly this velocity in the oppose direction. The velocity of the surface of the smaller cylinder due to rotation is $r\dot{\phi}$. Equating the two (you can convince yourself that the directions are right and we don't need negative signs), we get $r\dot{\phi}=(R+r)\dot{\theta}$, or $r(\dot{\phi}-\dot{\theta})=R\dot{\theta}$. Integrating this expression and assuming that $\phi=\theta=0$ at $t=0$, we get the desired result.